# How to change the number of rows in the textarea using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea, jquery-events

I have a textarea with 5 lines. I want to show only one line and on focus it should show remaining 4 lines.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
     $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#moo').focus(function(){
        $(this).attr('rows', '4');
    });
});
```

where moo is your textarea.

Answer (score 6):

```
jQuery(function($){
  $('#foo').focus(function(){
    $(this).attr('rows',5);
  }).blur(function(){
    $(this).attr('rows',1);
  });
});
```

Or, using less jQuery, less typing, and getting a hair more performance:

```
jQuery(function($){
  $('#foo')
    .focus(function(){ this.rows=5 })
    .blur( function(){ this.rows=1 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#textboxid').focus(function()
    {
       $(this).animate({'height': '185px'}, 'slow' );//Expand the textarea on clicking on it
       return false;
     });
```

Comment: :Please be more descriptive about your solution. Refer:[How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer)