# meteor capture event on afFielInput when textarea resise

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor-autoform

In a form I have

```
{{> afFieldInput id='idMeContacterInputMessage' class="formInput"    name='message' type='textarea' rows=3
                        style="position:absolute; top:22px; left:0px; width:380px;"}}
```

and

```
Template.meContacter.rendered =function(){
    $('#idMeContacterInputMessage').autosize()
.....
```

autosize() is from 'copleykj:jquery-autosize'

This is Ok.
The textarea element is automatically resized for entering characters.

I would now like to capture the event corresponding to the resizing of my textarea

I tried this without success

```
Template.meContacter.rendered =function(){
    $('#idMeContacterInputMessage').autosize()
    var ta = document.getElementById('idMeContacterInputMessage');
    ta.addEventListener('autosize:resized', function(){
        console.log('textarea height updated');
    });
```

Please, is there anyone can help me?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I've not tested this, but going by the example stated, it seems to be similar to what you're asking.

1. [Approach 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4417161/how-to-change-the-number-of-rows-in-the-textarea-using-jquery)
2. [Approach 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341496/javascript-how-to-get-the-height-of-text-inside-of-a-textarea)

If you take a look at approach 1, you can bind to input event and constantly check the number of rows of the textarea. If it is > 3, then set a reactive variable (a Session, maybe) to make it do whatever you want to do next.